# Initialize python dataclass with an openpyxl object

Tags: python, python-3.7, openpyxl, python-dataclasses

I have python class that is a get initialized with openpyxl Cell object. It a traditional cell class that accepts the Cell objects and reads some of the attributes of the Cell object and stores it as its own,

```
import openpyxl as oxl
class oxl_cell_objectclass(object):
    def __init__(self, cell):
        self.cell = cell
        self.xl_column = cell.column
        self.xl_row = cell.row
        self.cell_value = cell.value
```

How would I do thin in a python dataclass (introduced in python 3.7 +). I tried the code shown below and it gives me an exception that cell not found,

```
@dataclass
class oxl_cell_dataclass:
    cell : oxl.cell.cell.Cell #openpyxl Cell object
    xl_column : oxl.cell.cell.Cell.column = cell.column #default value for xl_column attribute
```

Comment: This looks to me like something you simply don't need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using inheritance. I had to make two changes to my code to make this work

- Inherit the openpyxl Cell object to make the code work
- Define a **post_init** function to assign the cell attributes

The working code is shown below,

```
@dataclass
class oxl_cell_dataclass(oxl.cell.cell.Cel):
    cell : oxl.cell.cell.Cell #openpyxl Cell object

    def __post_init__(self):
       self.xl_column = self.cell.column
```